# Orchard CMS: Add a stylesheet to a page

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

Setup:

I am using Orchard CMS 1.6.

I have a site where I need to be able to set the background color of the whole page.  Ie, I need to style the body tag.

I could use the LayoutSelector module and have distinct layouts.  However, the only difference in each layout is that the background-color rule for the body tag is different.  So it seems a very un-dry way of doing things.

I can't find any way to make Vandelay.Classy add a distinct id or class to the body tag (it adds, as I understand it) an id or a class to the outer tag of a content type.  In my case, that isn't the body tag.

So that is no good, I really do need to customize the body tag.

How to do this?

Note:

I need 3 different background colors.  I also have a two column layout and a three column layout.  [I use (a modified version of) the layoutSelector module to achieve this.]  So to have 3 different colors of background, and I used layouts to achieve this, I would need 6 different layouts:  TOTAL overkill.

There must be a better way...

Answer (score 0):

From any cshtml file, you should be able to access the Layout shape. From pretty much anywhere else, you can still get to the Layout shape through WorkContextAccessor. Once you have a reference to the Layout shape, you can do `Layout.Classes.Add("the-class-you-want")`.

Comment: So if I do Layout.Classes.Add, will that class be added to the body tag?  What about adding a whole style sheet?  Surely there is a way to do this?  That way I could override the existing styling (although I would need to set the order of the stylesheets for this to work...)

Comment: It depends how your layout.cshtml and document.cshtml are written, but in any case the class should be added to an element that is high enough in the tree to enable your scenario. Try it...
As for adding a stylesheet, it's even easier: just call Style.Include.

Comment: you have misunderstood me completely.  I want to add a stylesheet for a given page in the Dashboard.

Comment: I have understood you just fine. You can't do it from the dashboard unless you develop a module for that (the Classy feature from the Vandelay.Industries module does something like that). I'm explaining you how you can build such a module, or how you can do it from your theme. You're welcome.

Comment: Thanks, nice to know I'm welcome.  I'll write the module for adding stylesheets.  Strikes me as necessary.